# replacement for fcntl function be used for porting project from linux to window

Tags: c++, linux, window, porting, fcntl

I am doing porting a project from Linux to Windows. This is the code.

```
CIOChannelFileGlib::CIOChannelFileGlib(int fd, std::shared_ptr<CDataSource> src, std::shared_ptr<CDataSink> sink){
int Flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
DChannel = g_io_channel_unix_new(fd);
DFileHandle = fd;

Flags &= CIOFactory::SFileOptions::ReadOnly | CIOFactory::SFileOptions::WriteOnly | CIOFactory::SFileOptions::ReadWrite;
DDataSource = src;
```

...

}

I have installed Mingw. I found the fcntl.h header. I included in to my project but it makes my project get so many errors. Therefore, I am not sure I used the right library. Could anyone tell me what function in window can used to replace fcntl function or what library should be used. Thank you.

Comment: Linux is not Windows and mingw can only do so much to mask the differences. You will have to adapt some code from the Linux way to the Windows way. This probably cannot be avoided, but [perhaps Cygwin can help](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: You mean if using Cygwin, I compile my project on Cygwin terminal like compile on linux terminal? But I am using VS, how could I use Cygwin and VS at the same time? Do you know which function on Window can be used to replace fcntl function? Thank you.

Comment: You can't, not really. Windows does files differently. [`GetFileAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesw) or [`GetFileAttributesEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesexw) will get you started, but you will probably also have to modify the flag handing below  the `fcntl` call because the flags in Windows don't map to those used by linux. I'm not sure what this all does or how it's going to be used, but see if you can use the C++17 `<filesystem>` library instead.